# How to apply different rules for different start_urls in python scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have

```
start_urls = `[a.com,b.com,c.com,....]`
```

I want to apply rule1 for a.com like link extractors, allow, deny and for b.com some diffrent rule and for c.com I dont want to apply the rules, just simply crawl the given URL.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to override the [`start_requests`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method and use custom methods with link extractors:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('http://a.com', self.parse_a)
    yield Request('http://b.com', self.parse_b)
    yield Request('http://c.com', self.parse_data)

def parse_a(self, response):
    links = LinkExtractor(
        # ... extract links from http://a.com
    ).extract_links(response)
    return (Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_data) for link in links)

def parse_b(self, response):
    links = LinkExtractor(
        # ... extract links from http://b.com
    ).extract_links(response)
    return (Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_data) for link in links)
```